# How to set the alasql output as Array

Tags: javascript, alasql

I need to set the alasql output as Array. Is it possible?

I don't find any method for this

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
var keys = Object.keys(alasql).map(function(e) {
  return [e];
});
var qLikes = alasql('SELECT * FROM ? WHERE [0] LIKE "%uery%"', [keys]);
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(qLikes, null, ' ');
var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/develop/dist/alasql.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With AlaSQL you can prepend `COLUMN OF` to your SQL to get out an array of values representing the first column in your dataset.

```
var qLikes = alasql('COLUMN OF SELECT * FROM ? WHERE [0] LIKE "%uery%"', [keys]);
```

Example

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
var keys = Object.keys(alasql).map(function(e) {
  return [e];
});
var qLikes = alasql('COLUMN OF SELECT * FROM ? WHERE [0] LIKE "%uery%"', [keys]);
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(qLikes, null, ' ');
var pre = document.getElementById('pre');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/agershun/alasql/develop/dist/alasql.min.js"></script>
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: it's that what I want. I can't understand why have I not thought of this? Thank you!

Comment: The [MATRIX modifier](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/MATRIX) is also fine.